# How to interact with a Terminal in python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I'm working on a small script. The script should open 3 terminals and interact with this terminals independently.

I am pretty understand that subprocess is the best way to do that. What I've done so far:

```
# /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

term1 = subprocess.Popen(["open", "-a", "Terminal"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
term1.communicate(input="pwd")
```

My problem is I cannot interact with a new terminal. this part `term1.communicate(input="pwd")` is not working. I cannot send a command to a new Terminal. I also tried `term1.communicate(input="pwd\n")` but nothing happens

Do you any ideas how can I do that?

P.S. I am using Mac OS.

Comment: Do you really need to open a new terminal for what you are trying to accomplish, or do you just need to run `pwd` and capture the output?

Comment: Also, `communicate` waits until the process has completed, Terminals generally don't exit until closed, so it makes sense that it does nothing.

Comment: @user2085282 in my case I have to run 2 commands: "sudo tcprelay telnet" and "tcprelay --portoffset [arg1] [arg2]" but problem is if I run one of the command without opening a new Terminal I will not be able to run the second until the first one is done/terminated. That's why I use this solution

Comment: Just a head's up, you don't want to be using sudo inside of your script. instead, check if you have elevated privileges using `os.getuid() == 0` and run the command as normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run both commands concurrently without opening terminals.

```
import subprocess
process1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l"])
process2 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l"])
```

If you run that code you will see that the directory is listed twice, interleaved together. You can expand this for your specific needs:

```
tcprelay1 = subprocess.Popen(["tcprelay", "telnet"])
tcprelay2 = subprocess.Popen(["tcprelay", "--portoffset [arg1] [arg2]")
```

Comment: problem is I have to use "sudo" commannd in tcprealy1 and have to communicate with this.

Comment: You're going to have to run your python script with sudo then, and be careful... You can still communicate with the processes, I just left that part out.